# How can I be notified when a TableView has been removed from the super view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have programmed in several other languages but this is basically my first ios app and I am struggling to correctly implement a UITableView.
After reading the documentation, the most common way to accomplish this is to create a class that is a subclass of UITableViewController. I have done this and I have implemented all data source protocol methods as well as the row selection method from the delegate protocol and gave it three properties.

The first one is the number of rows in the tableview, 
the second is an array of the items to be displayed as labels in the table view, 
and finally there is a property to hold the text of the label from the selected row. 
Once the row is selected, I set the property of that holds this label and then I remove the table form the view with `[self.view removeFromSuperView]`.

The above isn't the only view in my app. The app is a color picker assignment, from school, so the main view contains all of the controls to manipulate the displayed color.

What I did after subclassing UITableViewController was, create an instance of this subclass in my main view controller and made it a property. So, on the main view is a recall button that allows the user to choose from a list of previously saved colors. When this button is clicked the this IBAction method is called

```
-(IBAction)swithToSavedColorsView:(id)sender {
self.savedColorTable.numberOfRows = self.dictionaryOfSavedColors.count;
NSLog( @"Count in switch view is %d", self.dictionaryOfSavedColors.count );
[ self.view addSubview:self.savedColorTable.view ];
```

}

This presents a list of the available saved colors and I respond to the row selection with

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
self.textFromColorSelection = [ [ NSString alloc ] init ];
UITableViewCell *cell = [ tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ];
self.textFromColorSelection = cell.textLabel.text;
NSLog(@"The value of selection is %@ ", self.textFromColorSelection );
[ self.view removeFromSuperview ]; // Go back to main screen.
```

}

As I was writing this code I was getting an erie feeling that I went about the creation of the UITableView in the completely wrong way from the beginning. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong as far as how I have communication between these objects set up.

The problem I am actually trying to solve is in the above method after i call 
`[ self.view removeFromSuperView ]`, how will my other view know when this has happened? What I want to do when the UITableView closes is have my other view get the label property from the instance I created and use that label to retrieve information out of a database.

Thanks for the help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need several controllers to respond to the dismissal of the table, you will likely want to use NSNotificationCenter in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear. More likely you are presenting from a viewController and only that viewController is waiting to learn what color was selected. I would suggest handling that with a delegate/protocol pattern.

Add something like this to your color pick table myColorPickTableController.h file above the @interface line:

```
@class myColorPickTableController;
@protocol myColorPickTableControllerDelegate
-(void)myColorPickTableControllerDidSelectColor:(UIColor *)selectedColor sender:(myColorPickTableController *)sender;
@end
```

Add a property in that header as well, to store reference to the delegate (the controller which is waiting to hear what color was picked).

```
@property(nonatomic, unsafe_unretained)id<myColorPickTableControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Now, replace the line

```
[ self.view removeFromSuperview ]; // Go back to main screen.
```

with

```
[delegate myColorPickTableControllerDidSelectColor:[UIColor whateverColorWasPicked] sender:self]; // Tell main screen user picked a color
```

Now in the presenting controller, you need to conform to the protocol by adding to your interface line

```
@interface myPresentingController : UIWhateverControllerIAm <myColorPickTableDelegate> // Add that part between <>
```

Now, in myPresentingController.m you implement the method

```
-(void)myColorPickTableControllerDidSelectColor:(UIColor *)selectedColor sender:(myColorPickTableController *)sender
{
  [self saveTheSelectedColor:selectedColor];
  [sender.view removeFromSuperview]; // I am not so sure about that, should be presenting, maybe modally or use navigation controller. Should work thought, not my first choice.
  sender = nil; // Just for good measure
}
```

Lastly, remember to make your presenting controller the delegate of the myColorPickTableController when you create it. Set delegate as self like so

```
myColorPickTableController *pickTable = [myColorPickTableController alloc] init];
pickTable.delegate = self.
```

Comment: Sorry it took me a few to get back to you but this solution worked perfectly. Thanks for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your subclassed `UITableViewController`, `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` should be called after your view is removed. Try sending a notification when your view disappears (look into `NSNotificationCenter`).

Comment: I chose the protocol delegate pattern instead and it worked like a charm thanks though.